# Why no 'i' in Albanian for digits from 0 to 9?

Tags: written-language

According to OEIS the only other alpha language that has no numbers 0 to 9 with an i is Albanian.
http://oeis.org/A159878
1 – një
2 – dy
3 – tre
4 – katër
5 – pesë
6 – gjashtë
7 – shtatë
8 – tetë
9 – nëntë
I wonder why so? Any historic reasons?
I noticed the similar situation for Latin.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's essentially just trivia - quirks of linguistic history and coincidences.

Comment: That claim is incorrect. First of all, there are plenty of non-Latin alphabetic languages (e.g. the numbers 0-9 in Russian and Greek don't have an <i>). Even if one limits oneself to Latin alphabets, then you also have languages wth no <i> in their numerals, like Pali, Selkup , Cheyenne, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numbers_in_various_languages#Indo-European_languages and Languages like Gujarati with no [i] sound in their numerals.

Comment: @MarkBeadles. I hope you realise that Pali does not use the Latin alphabet.

Comment: @MikhailGaichenkov So are you looking for the *sound* [i] or the letter <i>? They are not the same thing. If the sound, then the Polish numerals contain no sound [i].

Comment: @MarkBeadles. I just read the comment in oeis, then did search at http://www.languagesandnumbers.com/how-to-count-in-serbian/en/srp/ where I found 'i' in Latin also. However, you said the Polish numbers contain no sound [i] also.

Comment: @MikhailGaichenkov The Polish numerals in IPA are /ˈzɛrɔ/ /ˈjɛdɛn/ /dva/ /tʂɨ/ /ˈtʂtɛrɨ/ /ˈpʲjɛɲtɕ/ /ˈʂɛɕtɕ/ /ˈɕɛdɛm/ /ˈɔɕɛm/ /ˈdʑɛvʲjɛɲtɕ/. The orthographic <i> in pięć, siedem, osiem and dziewięć is a modifier on the previous consonant.

Comment: @fdb Indian scripts are alphabets as well, even if obviously the author of the question is not aware of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not accept that this is a trivial question. In Proto-Indo-European (as usually reconstructed) the only one of the lower numbers that has the vowel /i/ is *tri-, the zero-grade of *trei- "three". This means that when the other lower numbers in IE daughter languages have the vowel /i/ this is a secondary development. Since Albanian has developed *treis to tre there is no reason why it should have /i/ in any of its lower numbers.

Comment: Thank you! Any referencies to read more about it?